# Can Android app launches be dynamically controlled or censored?

Tags: java, android, launcher

I am interested in developing a custom Android launcher which would be installed onto a device primarily for censorship. Ideally a device would divert attempts to launch applications to a service which would decide, based on a profile, whether the user would be allowed to proceed, or be shown a block screen/redirected to an informational web page.

Is it possible to detect and interrupt application launches via some kind of background service or attachable listener? Or alternatively, might it be possible to have a launcher launch a different application than the one clicked on, in order to allow for indirection?

Or, if all of this is impossible, can a service running as part of a custom launcher dynamically hide/unhide launch icons based on triggering events/messages?

Comment: Replacing the launcher would give you some control over how things are launched *from the launcher*, but that is not the only way to launch, nor can a launcher prevent itself from being replaced.

Comment: It is actually possible to lock users into a launcher - exiting it can be password protected, that combined with setting the launcher as default seems to achieve this (setting aside the possibility of the user starting in recovery mode, etc).

Comment: it's precisely because of recovery mode that deselecting the malicious launcher cannot be prevented.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to catch an app being launched and redirect that.  If you think about all the horrible things people could do with this it's easy to see why. I think you're going about this in the wrong way.  Instead of trying to enforce these rules with a custom launcher you should look into one of the Mobile Device Management options that are available for Android or work on creating your own.